# grouping by hour in $group (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this data time in mongo collection:

```
{   
 ...
 "CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2017-03-06T08:16:02.930Z"),
 ...
},
....
{   
 ...
 "CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2018-03-06T08:16:04.030Z"),
 ...
},...
```

I want to grouping my collection by hour. Means i want to those documents are in 8 o'clock comes in same group and those documents are in 9 o'clock comes in same group. because i want to select first document in same group. Someone have any logic or idea for this grouping with it's accumulator Operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only particular hour then you can use [$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) in aggregation framework, like below:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $hour: "$CreationDateTime" },
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

MongoDB will set `8` as a grouping `_id` for your docs. Otherwise if you need one hour as an interval, you have to use `$dayOfMonth`, `$month` and `$years` like below

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                h: { $hour: "$CreationDateTime" },
                d: { $dayOfMonth: "$CreationDateTime" } ,
                m: { $month: "$CreationDateTime" } ,
                y: { $year: "$CreationDateTime" } ,
            },
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            firstDoc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

And in that case you're gonna get `{ "h" : 8, "d" : 6, "m" : 3, "y" : 2017 }` as a grouping `_id`

Comment: Thanks dude. I do this way but why my result is not sorted: http://codepad.org/eRQBKY4P    this my code: http://codepad.org/G4gIJ8MW  ....And how could i get first element of each `docs` in document to sending next stage in my pipeline?  @micki

Comment: @sayreskabir simply add firstDoc: `{ $first: "$$ROOT" }` like in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

> you can mapReduce utility like

```
db.collection.mapReduce(function(){

  var hour = this.CreationDateTime.getHour()
  emit(this.hour,this)
},function(key,values){
 return JSON.stringify(values);
},{out:{inline:true}});
```

Comment: I want to do with aggregation framework.how can i do this?

Comment: kindly check mongo document for $push operator with aggregate framework https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Answer (score 0):

> **this is an aggregate framework solution.  **

```
db.collection.aggregate(
       [
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$CreationDateTime",
               items: { $push:  { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field1" } }
             }
         }
       ]
    )
```